# Checking through a variable to see if it doesn't contains anymore strings

Tags: python

```
def main():
    #word = input("Word to guess for player 2:")
    word = ['h','e','l','l','o']
    word2 = "hello"
    #make a list of _ the same length as the word
    display =[]
    for i in range (0,len(word)):
        display.append("_")

    chances = int(input("Number of chances to guess word:"))
    if len(word)== 11:
        print ("Your word is too long. It has to be 10 charecters or less")
    else:
        word = word
    if chances < len(word):
        answer = input("Your word is {0} letters long , are you sure you don't want more chances? Yes or no?". format (len(word)))
        if answer == "no":
            chances= int(input("Number of chances:"))
        else:
            chances = chances
            ("Ok then lets continue with the game")
    print ("Player 2, you have {0} chances to guess the word.". format (chances))
    won = False
    underscore = False
    while chances > 0 and won == False and underscore == False:
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
        gC=False

        for i in range (0,len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                gC=True
                display[i]=guess

        if not gC:
            chances = chances - 1

        display2 = ""
        for i in display:
            display2 = display2 + i + " "
```

For some reason the code doesn't work when I state my while loop as the game continues to go on until the user runs out of guess'. Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I  can fix this?

Comment: Use `while chances > 0 and not won and not underscore`; testing if a boolean `== False` or `== True` should never be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You never set `won` to True when the user wins the game by guessing all the letters.

Comment: also underscore is never set to true either, not sure what that's for.

Comment: I forgot to include this piece of code in my program: for i in display:
    if  "_" not in display:
            underscore = True
    if not underscore:
           won = True

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your original question, instead more of a code-review, but maybe you'll find it useful.

```
word = list('hello')  # replaces manual splitting of string into letters

display = [ '_' ] * len(word)  # replaces build-up using for-loop

chances = input("Number ... ")  # already returns int if the user enters an int
                                # but will evaluate any valid python expression the
                                # user enters; this is a security risk as what
                                # ever is done this way will be done using your
                                # permissions
chances = int(raw_input("Number ..."))  # probably what you wanted

...
else:
    word = word  # does nothing.  remove this line and the "else:" above

chances -= 1  # replaces 'chances = chances - 1' and does the same

display2 = ' '.join(display)  # replaces the for-loop to build display2
```

Furthermore I suggest to use better names.  Variables like `display2` or `gC` aren't very helpful in this context.  In professional programming you always have to keep in mind that you are writing your code (also or even mainly) for the next developer who has to maintain it.  So make it readable and understandable.  Choose names like `displayString` or `guessedCorrectly` instead.